# coefficients in the glm procedure in sas with a class variable

Tags: sas

I think my brain is mush. 
When I use a class variable in SAS in the glm procedure, I no longer get coefficient estimates.

Is there still a way to get coefficient estimates and use one (or more) class variables?

```
proc glm data=mydata;
  class sex;
    model dep=indep1 indep2 sex;
        run;
```

If I remove the class statement, everything works hunky dory. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You should still get coefficient estimates for sex. How is it coded, and what does the log say?

Comment: The log doesnt really offer anything. Everything looks to run find. The output just offers Type 1 SS and Type III SS. Ive tried to code sex as both a numeric and a character variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, add the /solution to your model statement. You should verify how the model is coding your class variable to make sure it is what you expect.

```
proc glm data=sashelp.class;
class sex;
model weight = height age sex/solution;
run;quit;
```